# jQuery, change css property when specific is in place

Tags: jquery

My jQuery code changes the height of my div from 200px to 100% on click. This works perfect. But I need to be that when I click it AGAIN, the same element, the div changes back to 200px. I have no idea how to do this except by an if statement but i'm not sure how I would see if a css property matches a certain css property.

Here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

        $("#port1").click(function() {
            $(".ppc").css("height","100%");
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#port1').toggle(function () {
    $(".ppc").css({height: "100%"});
}, function () {
    $(".ppc").css({height: "200px"});
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Works better than the other codes posted sorry everyone else. Sorry my last comment is useless it doesn't have a delay that was my transition that wasn't working so it just delayed.

Answer (score 2):

define a css class with height 100%, on click, then toggle class

CSS

```
.classname {
    height: 100%
}
```

JS

```
    $("#port1").click(function() {
        $(".ppc").toggleClass('classname');
    });
```

it's always a good idea to add styles using css class, so it is easy to add/remove and less js code if you need to add a whole bunch of styles

Comment: there are other cases where toggle is not good for your use. In those situations you can check class with .hasClass('classname') if true then do something and if false do something else

Answer (score 2):

You could add a variable that says var isPort1Max = false;

Then you can set it in the onclick function.

```
var isPort1Max = false;

function() {
    if (isPort1Max){
        $(".ppc").css("height","100%");
        isPort1Max=true;
    else {
        $(".ppc").css("height","200px");
        isPort1Max=false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm trying to keep it all in jQuery because the rest of my code is but nice code.

Answer (score 2):

Define a class for both and use toggleClass, or use the following:

```
$("#port1").click(function() {
    $(".ppc").css("height", function(i, val) {
        return val == '200px' ? '100%' : '200px';
    });
});
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t24CN/)